# how to increment tuple values and search a string in a loop in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have this code.

```
 arfffile = []

inputed = raw_input("Enter Evaluation for name including file extension...")

reader = open(inputed, 'r')

verses = []

for line in reader:
    verses.append(line)

for line in verses:
    if line.split('@') == "@":
        verses.pop(line)


numclusters = int(raw_input("Enter the number of clusters"))

clusters = {}

for i in range(1,numclusters+1):
    clusters["cluster"+str(i)] = 0



print clusters
 # If verse belongs to a cluster, increment the cluster count by one in the dictionary value.
for verse in verses:
    for k in clusters:
        if k in verse:
            clusters[k] += 1
        else:
            print "not in"

print clusters

yeslist = []

for verse in verses:
    for k in clusters:
        if k not in yeslist:
            yeslist.append((k,0))
        elif k in yeslist:
            print "already in" + k


for verse in verses:
    for k in clusters:
        if k in verse and "Yes" in verse:
            yeslist.append(yeslist.index(k), +1)


    # iterate through dictionary and iterate through the lines
    # need to read in file line by line, 



    # if "yes" and cluster x increment cluster 
    # need to work out percentage of possitive verses in each cluster.
```

an example of the arff file is

```
@relation tester999.arff_clustered

@attribute Instance_number numeric
@attribute allah numeric
@attribute day numeric
@attribute lord numeric
@attribute people numeric
@attribute earth numeric
@attribute men numeric
@attribute truth numeric
@attribute verily numeric
@attribute chapter numeric
@attribute verse numeric
@attribute CLASS {Yes,No}
@attribute Cluster {cluster1,cluster2,cluster3}

@data
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster3
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,No,cluster3
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,No,cluster3
3,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,4,No,cluster3
4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,No,cluster3
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,6,No,cluster3
6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,7,No,cluster3
7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,No,cluster3
8,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,No,cluster3
9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,No,cluster3
10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,No,cluster3
11,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,5,No,cluster2
```

As it stands the program reads in the data lines eg

```
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster3
```

and i have created a dictionary that detects how many clusters are in the data files. In this example there are 3. cluster1 cluster2 and cluster3. The code then appends each cluster as a key value represented as a string in the dictionary "clusters"
Then i iterate over all verses and count each line to see which cluster it belongs to.

My next step is to try to count, for each cluster, the number of times a line with "Yes" in it occurs. so say there are 10 lines with "yes" in the string for each line in the data, the code should be able to count the number of occurences of this.

So far the code i have done is here

```
for verse in verses:
        for k in clusters:
            if k in verse and "Yes" in verse:
                yeslist.append(yeslist.index(k), +1)
```

i`m basicaly creating a list of tuples called "yeslist" with values like this [ (cluster1, 0), (cluster2, 3)]

So for each line(represented as a string), check if there is a "Yes" in it, if there is check which cluster it belongs to then incremenet that tuple value by one.

I`m having trouble thinking of the logic of how to do this... Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: and the short variant of the question is?

Comment: i'm pretty sure tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

inputed = raw_input("Enter Evaluation for name including file extension...")

reader = open(inputed, 'r')

verses = [ line.strip() for line in reader.readlines() if line[0] != '@' ]

reader.close()

cluster_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
yes_count = collections.defaultdict(int)

verse_infos = [ (split_verse[-1],split_verse[-2]) for split_verse \
                 in verses.split(",") ]

for verse in verse_infos:
    cluster_count[verse[0]]+=1
    if verse[1] == 'yes':
        yes_count[verse[0]]+=1
```

You end up with two dictionaries:

```
cluster_count : keys = cluster#, values = count
yes_count     : keys = cluster#, values = #yes
```

if you really want a list of tuples:

```
yes_tuples = ( x for x in sorted(yes_count.iteritems()) )
```